# Webpack Disable HMR for Single File

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-hmr

Trying to figure out a HMR setup for a project with a centralized state object that I don't want to reload (not Redux/React).

What's the rough pattern for creating a module that always rejects reloads?

```
let state = {};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./', () => {
    // ???
  });
}
```

Most of the app requires this state file directly, so I need to make sure that the module isn't swapped out.

Comment: If you are using React Hot Loader 3, I recommend you read this thread: https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/281

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora Thanks, but I _explicitly_ mentioned that I'm not using React in this project.